# Quicksort Divide and Conquer

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement **Quicksort** using the *divide and conquer technique*. I am getting a ***Stack Overflow error in the recursion calls***. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> unsorted = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    unsorted.add(23);
    unsorted.add(5);
    unsorted.add(1);
    unsorted.add(-8);
    unsorted.add(101);
    unsorted.add(21);
    unsorted.add(10);
    unsorted.add(10);
    unsorted.add(0);
    unsorted.add(50);

    ArrayList<Integer> sorted = Quicksort(unsorted);
    System.out.println(sorted.toString());
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> Quicksort(ArrayList<Integer> unsorted) {

    if (unsorted.size() <= 1)
        return unsorted;

    ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> more = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int pivotindex = unsorted.size()/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) {
        if (unsorted.get(i) < unsorted.get(pivotindex))
            less.add(unsorted.get(i));
        else
            more.add(unsorted.get(i));
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> sorted = Quicksort(less);
    sorted.add(unsorted.get(pivotindex));
    sorted.addAll(Quicksort(more));

    return sorted;
}
```

I want it to implement using `ArrayLists`. Can anyone point out where I am wrong?

***Thanks a lot.***

Comment: As it is, any value equal to the pivot (including the pivot itself) gets added to the `more` list.

Comment: The error seems to lie in the fact that you are, on each run of the method, adding a duplicate of `pivotindex`. When you are iterating through unsorted, there is no check for if the value equals the pivotindex and so it gets added to the `more` arraylist. You then add it again at `sorted.add(unsorted.get(pivotindex))` and so the array grows forever which leads to your stackoverflow error.

Comment: Within the for-loop, you are comparing the element at the pivot index to itself, and adding it to the sorted list eventually as the less or more section, AND as the element at the pivot index. Therefor, at every recursion call, you are increasing the size of the list, and the calls never end

Comment: `using ArrayList` if this was [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I'd point out that you still should be programming against interfaces, not classes: declare `unsorted`, `less` and `more` `List<Comparable>` (or even `Collection<>` if you don't insist on pivot from the middle - which reminds me: use a local variable for the pivot, not its index). Use constructors with a plausible estimate of size for `Collection`s providing such.

Answer (score 5):

You should keep your `pivot` value in a separate place from the `more` and `less` lists.

Change the condition to:

```
else if(unsorted.get(i) > unsorted.get(pivotindex))
        more.add(unsorted.get(i));
```

It should work fine. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comment by Josh, this wouldn't work if there are multiple elements having the same value as the pivot. For this, what you can do is define another ArrayList called `equal` and add this line:

```
else
    equal.add(unsorted.get(i));
```

Then append this list along with the `pivot` element when you merge the array back.

Thanks for pointing this out. :)

**Note:** This sort won't be guaranteed to be *stable* (as elements having same value **might not** be placed according to their relative positions in the original array).

Comment: Will this still work if there are multiple elements of the same value as the pivot element...? Those elements would be lost using this method, as you are not adding them to the sorted list. See my answer below, where I hold onto them, and add them to the sorted list.

Comment: I guess for that problem the clever solution would be to define another arraylist called `equal` and then place it along with the pivot when you concatenate the array back.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a solution that can be understood easily

```
ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> equal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> more = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int pivotindex = unsorted.size()/2;

for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) {
    if (unsorted.get(i) < unsorted.get(pivotindex)) //Put whatever is less to the left
        less.add(unsorted.get(i));
    else if (unsorted.get(i) == unsorted.get(pivotindex)) //Put whatever is equal in the middle
        equal.add(unsorted.get(i));
    else //Put everything else to the right (everything greater)
        more.add(unsorted.get(i));
}

ArrayList<Integer> sorted = Quicksort(less); //Sort the left, then add
sorted.addAll(equal); //Middle is already sorted (all equal), add
sorted.addAll(Quicksort(more)); //Sort the right, then add

return sorted;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works perfectly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         ArrayList<Integer> unsorted = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            unsorted.add(23);
            unsorted.add(5);
            unsorted.add(1);
            unsorted.add(-8);
            unsorted.add(101);
            unsorted.add(21);
            unsorted.add(10);
            unsorted.add(10);
            unsorted.add(0);
            unsorted.add(50);

            ArrayList<Integer> sorted = Quicksort(unsorted);
            System.out.println(sorted.toString());
        }

        public static ArrayList<Integer> Quicksort(ArrayList<Integer> unsorted) {
                System.out.println(unsorted.size());
            if (unsorted.size() <= 1)
                return unsorted;

            ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> more = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            int pivotindex = unsorted.size()/2;

            for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) {
                if (unsorted.get(i) < unsorted.get(pivotindex))
                    less.add(unsorted.get(i));
                else
                    more.add(unsorted.get(i));
            }
            if(less.isEmpty()) {
                less.add(more.remove(more.size() - 1));
            }

            ArrayList<Integer> sorted = Quicksort(less);
            //sorted.add(unsorted.get(pivotindex));
            sorted.addAll(Quicksort(more));

            return sorted;
        }
```